# Calculating the tip

Tags: python

```
print 'Bill calculator'
Name=raw_input ('What is your name?')
p=raw_input ('How many people are there?')
t=raw_input ('What percentage tip would you like to pay?')
b=raw_input ('How much was your bill?')


x = float(b)
tip=(x*float(t))/100
print 'your tip for the inputted bill is',tip,

total= b + tip
print 'The total amount of the bill',total,

print 'amount per person', (total/int(p))
```

Have an error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Comp Sci\Bill calculator.py", line 12, in <module>
    total= b + tip
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects,
```

Comment: What type is `b`? Where have you set it? Also, read the error message again.

Comment: @Veedrac was not being rude at all, just trying to get clarifications in order to answer the question. He or she is also trying to help, and accusing of rudeness and whining isn't going to help.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is right in the error message:

> File "H:\Comp Sci\Bill calculator.py", line 12, in total= b + tip TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

`b` is is set from a raw input, which means it is a `string`. You have to change it to `float` in order to use it in mathematic operations with other `float`s:

```
total = float(b) + tip
```

Sometimes the answer is just in plain sight ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want `total = x + tip` instead of `total= b + tip`. `b` is a string you've read from the input. Later you convert it into a `float` (with this line: `x = float(b)`) and the purpose of that is to use it in arithmetic operations.